# Update account passphrase over RPC(using web3)?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, accounts

Like web3.personal.lockAccount() and web3.personal.newAccount() is there any method available or any other API's exist to update account passphrase over RPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No unfortunately.

You can see the range of commands currently offered in the [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) `personal` API in [web3.js/lib/web3/methods/personal.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/e4eb9606aa0aa10fd3eeb0a5e5d67c4fff43e814/lib/web3/methods/personal.js), and this does not include any methods for updating passwords.

The [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) does not include any methods for updating your password.

Even using the `geth` command, you can only update your account password interactively. From [Managing your accounts - Updating an existing account](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#updating-an-existing-account):

> Since only one password can be given, only format update can be performed, **changing your password is only possible interactively**.